# Javascript/jquery to validate the form in button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi i have a class using needs validate in form is there a way for me to validate this on button submit onclick ? or a better way to improve the coding for this ?

Where i can even call the invalid feedback ?
and also when button click it will check the valdiation first before call the database

As this code got some problem later in the end where i couldnt validate anything when button click as it passes to the database immediately without the validation check .

```js
(function validateForm() {
  'use strict';
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
  Array.from(forms)
    .forEach(function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false)
    })
})();
```

```html
<form id="form" class="needs-validation" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

  <!-- <label id="mandatoryField" class="hiddenfield" hidden>* is mandatory</label> -->

  <div class="form-group row nameform">
    <label for="validationName" class="col-form-label nameadduser">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-6">
      <input name="validationName" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationName" placeholder="Name" title="Name can be any. e.g. john" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Enter a Name!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationEmail" class="col-form-label emailadduser">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-6">
      <input name="validationEmail" type="email" class="form-control emails" id="validationEmail" placeholder="example1@gmail.com" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"
        required>
      <div style="margin-left: 3px;" class="invalid-feedback">
        Enter a correct Email format!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationUserName" class="col-form-label usernameadduser">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-6 ">
      <input name="validationUserName" type="text" class="form-control " id="validationUserName" placeholder="Username" pattern="^(?=.{4,}$)(?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:[a-zA-Z\d])*)+$" title="Username should be at least 4 letter" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Username must meet the following requirements:

        <b>At least four letter</b>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationpassword" class="col-form-label oldpasswordadduser">Old<br>&#10;Password:</label>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex">
      <input name="validationpassword" type="password" class="form-control pass" id="oldpasswords" placeholder="Password" required>
      <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="toggleoldPassword"></i>
      <!-- <div style="margin-left: 15px;" class="invalid-tooltip password-empty" >
                                    Enter a password!
                                </div> -->

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex">
      <input name="validationpassword" onChange="onChange()" type="password" class="form-control pass" id="passwords" placeholder="Password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{7,}$" title="Password should be like this. e.g. A123de!123"
        required>
      <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
      <!-- <div style="margin-left: 15px;" class="invalid-tooltip password-empty" >
                                    Enter a password!
                                </div> -->
      <div id="passwordvalidator" class="invalid-tooltip password-notmeet">
        Password must meet the following requirements:
        <br><br>
        <label class="color-text"> At least one capital letter</label>
        <br>
        <label class="color-text"> At least one special character</label>
        <br>
        <label class="color-text"> At least one number</label>
        <br>
        <label class="color-text"> Be at least 7 letter</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationconfirmpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">Re-enter<br>&#10;Password:</label>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex">
      <input name="validationconfirmpassword" onChange="onChange()" type="password" class="form-control confirmpass" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
      <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="toggleconfirmPassword"></i>
      <div style="margin-left: 20px;" class="invalid-tooltip">
        Password do not match or value is null!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="passwordconfirm"></div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationRole" class="col-form-label role">Role:</label>
    <div class="col-3 ">
      <select class="select-user-role custom-select-sm col-11" id="select-user-role" required>
        <option class="selectrole" selected disabled value="">Select ....</option>
      </select>
      <div style="margin-left: 10px;" class="invalid-feedback">
        Enter a valid user role!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row placeholderimage">
    <img src="" id="output" width="400" height="400" style="border-radius: 50%;" />

    <input id="file-upload-input" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL(event);">
  </div>



  <button id="submitbtn" type="submit" class="btn-primary submitbutton" disabled>Done</button>

</form>
```

I have a button onclick where i got my database out when click which is this code it is with sweetalert as well not sure do we need to put the prevent button for validation here ?

```js
$('#submitbtn').click(function() {

  //get input value field
  var name = $('#validationName').val();
  var email = $('#validationEmail').val();
  var username = $('#validationUserName').val();
  var oldpassword = $('#oldpasswords').val();
  var password = $('#passwords').val();
  var picture = document.getElementById("output").src;
  var role = $('#select-user-role').val();

  //making ajax call after this retrieve

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8090/api/postWithRawBody",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
    headers: {
      // Generally used for queries that we're planning to use
      query: `UserUpdate(,'${formatParamString(name)}','${formatParamString(username)}','${formatParamString(email)}','','${formatParamString(password)}','','${formatParamString(role)}')`,
      // apikey like oXkPNt3p6cuDobzBVjpsPUyawSYDFqFHVWPkijXZZstjVPLLWo
      "Content-Type": "text/plain",
      apikey: sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
    },
    dataType: "text",
    // May be quite long
    // Usually an array
    // Only for specific conditions
    data: `UserUpdate(${getQueryInfo()["id"]},'${formatParamString(name)}','${formatParamString(username)}','${formatParamString(email)}','${formatParamString(oldpassword)}','${formatParamString(password)}','${formatParamString(picture)}','${formatParamString(role)}')`,


    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      // showing response from API
      // showing response box that is added
      //console.log(data)

      $('#response').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>" + "<b>Success!</b> The information have been updated <b>successfully</b>" + "</div>")

      Swal.fire({
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'Update Successfully!',
          html: 'The information have been updated successfully!<br>By pressing <b>okay</b> this page will go to <b>view users</b> page',

          showCancelButton: true,
          cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          allowEscapeKey: false,
          confirmButtonText: 'Okay',
          cancelButtonColor: '#9b3be7', // purple
          confirmButtonColor: '#79b446', // light green
          heightAuto: false,

        })
        // footer: '<label class="fixissue">How to fix this issue?</label><br>Try to change the username input and press add button again'
        .then(function(inputvalue) {
          if (inputvalue.isConfirmed) {
            window.location.assign('viewUsers.html?id=' + getQueryInfo()['id'])

          } else if (inputvalue.isCancel) {
            Swal.fire('')
          }

        })


    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, err) {
      if (xhr["status"] == 409) {
        $('#response').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>" + "<b>Error!</b> There is an <b>duplicate</b> on username!" + "</div>")
        //then
        // setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); },5000); //reload a page after 5 seconds
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: '<div class="color-text">Update not success!</div>',
          html: 'There is an <label class="color-text"><b>duplicate</b></label> on username!<br><label class="fixissue">Solution ✔</label><br>Try to change the <b>username</b> and press <b>add</b> again',
          heightAuto: false,
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          allowEscapeKey: false
          // footer: '<label class="fixissue">How to fix this issue?</label><br>Try to change the username input and press add button again'

        })
      }
      if (xhr["status"] == 400) {
        $('#response').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>" + "<b>Error!</b> The <b>old password </b> is incorrect!" + "</div>")
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: '<div class="color-text">Update not success!</div>',
          html: 'The <label class="color-text"><b>old password</b></label> is incorrect!<br><label class="fixissue">Solution ✔</label><br>Try to change the <b>old password</b> and press <b>add</b> again',
          heightAuto: false,
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          allowEscapeKey: false
          // footer: '<label class="fixissue">How to fix this issue?</label><br>Try to change the username input and press add button again'

        })

      }
      // if (xhr["status"] == "(failed)") {
      //     $('#response').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>"+"<b>Error!</b> There is an <b>duplicate</b> on username! where you cant add in image"+"</div>")

      // }
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Maybe this helps
https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: what is your function `validateForm()`?

Comment: hi let me update the valdiateform it could be the problem 
I have added the validateForm()